# LWC on Lightning Page showing spinner continously

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-page

I have an LWC component and want to use it on lightning record page but when I am using it on lightning page, it's working fine for admin users but for other users, it's showing spinner forever. I am not able to find the cause of the issues.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] this post to provide the elements of code required to reproduce this problem. See [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: can you add some component lines and controller lines to understand your issue?

Comment: It was a profile permission issue.  given permission to profile on apex class and now working fine.